# What caused quadrupole anisotropy at the time of recombination?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, observable-universe

The polarization of CMB requires a quadrupole anisotropy of the incident radiation field acting on the plasma. How did such a special pattern (i.e. hot and cold in two orthogonal directions) generate in the first place? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Quadrupole Types and Polarization Patterns](http://background.uchicago.edu/~whu/intermediate/Polarization/polar4.html)

> Quadrupole anisotropies are associated with density, vorticity and gravitational wave fluctuations
>
> Their projection determines the polarization pattern and may be distinguished by symmetry properties
>
> The polarization probe more than just the density or temperature fluctuations at recombination.  Because the polarization pattern is a projection of the quadrupole anisotropy, any source of quadrupole anisotropy leaves its imprint in the polarization.
>
> n general there are three sources to the quadrupole anisotropy at recombination:

For example :

> A passing gravitational wave causes an anisotropic stretching of space and correspondingly the frequency of CMB photons.  This also produces a quadrupolar variation in the temperature.  Importantly, it is not symmetric like the density quadrupole.  This asymmetry causes a "handedness" to the pattern of polarization.

Comment: Thanks, @annav. Can you tell that apart from gravitational waves what else could cause quadrupole anisotropy and how?

Comment: @SRS the three terms described in the first quoted sentence,density and vorticity., the anisotropic distribution of mass